# Simple Python comprehension for dictionary

Tags: python

Is there a way to write this as a comprehension?

```
sd = {}
for x in range(n):
    sd[x] = []
```

Comment: Yes `sd = {x: [] for x in range(n)}`

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx that is not a list comprehension, that is a dict comprehension..the answer is no because the output is not a list

Comment: @DerekEden yes, I know. I'm saying yes for his question of **is it possible**

Comment: But it isnt possible to write that as a list comprehension I challenge you to do it

Comment: @DerekEden Challenge accepted: `sd = [{x: [] for x in range(n)} for _ in range(1)][0]`

Answer (score 3):

You mean *dictionary* comprehension. That is the equivalent of:

```
sd = {x:[] for x in range(n)}
```